# ApiPlatform with subfolder url does not show up the documentation

Tags: symfony, apache2, api-platform.com, mod-proxy

I'm developing my API v2 on ApiPlatform.

This will run in a docker on one of my servers using Apache's mod_proxy.

Here is what I added within my server conf file so that `https://myapi/v2` serves the correct container

```
ProxyPass /v2/ https://127.0.0.1:7054/
ProxyPassReverse /v2/ https://127.0.0.1:7054/
```

The default documentation does not know how to fetch public resources with /v2 after the domain "myapi".
[image]

I understand that the ApiPlatform mechanism uses "asset" so it should automatically take the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

here's some suggestions:

1. run: `composer require symfony/requirements-checker` This will put a folder name *bundles/* in your public dir
2. Add the following line in your apache configuration file:
   *ProxyPassMatch ^/bundles/(.*)$ https://127.0.0.1:7054/*
3. Reload apache2

Hope this will help...